# Impossible to add my jar with scope in my project maven

Tags: java, maven

Sorry for the spelling, I'm french

I try to install with scope a jar for oracle in my project

Here my pom.xml

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:/Users/bin/Desktop/dossier_access/instantclient_12_1/ojdbc7.jar</systemPath>
          </dependency>
```

The maven compile didn't function

I did after (it works)

```
mvn -X install:install-file -Dfile=C:/Users/bin/Desktop/dossier_access/instantclient_12_1/ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar -DpomFile=C:/Users/Documents/Projets/version7/integration-archetype/batch/packaging/integration-archetype-batch/pom.xml
```

but mvn install gives :

```
[WARNING] The POM for oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for oracle.jdbc:ucp:jar:12.1.0.2 is missing, no dependency information available
BUILD FAILURE
```

Thank you for your responses,
i'm beginner with Maven and I have already see on the other posts...

Answer (score 2):

What i usually do is first install jdbc driver in local repository so it is available for all apps in local machine. 
Then just use regular dependency tag to include it in you pom file.

Look at this quick tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/

Answer (score 1):

After installing a 3rd party into your local repo (that is what you did with mvn install:install-file) you can reference it the following way:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
```

And no path information is required anymore.

Comment: A tip: `system`-scoped dependencies are never looked up in the local repository. If `install:install-file` was indeed successful, remove the `<scope>` tag above.

Comment: I tried with scope and unless scope i have always : The following artifacts could not be resolved: oracle.jdbc:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2, oracle.jdbc:ucp:jar:12.1.0.2...

Comment: I verified in C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.2, there is ojdbc7.jar but also a pom.xml

Comment: Are you referring to the jdbc driver with groupname "oracle.jdbc" anywhere? In the excerpts above it was consistently "com.oracle".

Comment: I tested with <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
but not functions

Comment: That was this! Thank you i ran "mvn clean install:install-file -Dfile=C:/Users/Documents/ucp.jar -DgroupId=ojdbc7.jdbc -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar"